# Large post request makes Nodejs server run out of heap memory

Tags: node.js, post, upload, heap-memory

I am running a NodeJS server and when it takes a large post request(>100mb), it fails due to heap out of memory.

I have tried setting --max-old-space-size=8000, but it didn't work at all even though I set it properly and checked that it is set to 8GB.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
GC[20429:0x3851890]    12498 ms: Mark-sweep 400.5 (420.8) -> 316.5 (336.7) MB, 7.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.3 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 1796 ms) (average mu = 0.991, current mu = 0.994) allocation failu[20429:0x3851890]    15081 ms: Mark-sweep 700.5 (720.8) -> 412.5 (432.7) MB, 114.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2583 ms) (average mu = 0.967, current mu = 0.956) allocation fai

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x3ac05b24fc5d]
Security context: 0x3661c71546f1 <JSObject>
    1: slice [0x3661c71409e9](this=0x0287971abf39 <Uint8Array map = 0x382c0352a4d1>,0)
    2: md5 [0x14615e91adb1] [/home/minjae/Dev/mednick_minjae/mednick_api_minjae/node_modules/md5/md5.js:16] [bytecode=0x16b93054ad39 offset=106](this=0x1dac4a782371 <JSGlobal Object>,0x0287971abf39 <Uint8Array map = 0x382c0352a4d1>,0x2eaf18e825b1 <undefined>)
    3: /* ano...

FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x95bd00 node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0x95cc46 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/bin/node]
 3: 0xb3dbde v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 4: 0xb3de14 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 5: 0xf3ce52  [/usr/bin/node]
 6: 0x105f567 v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::New(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag, v8::internal::MinimumCapacity) [/usr/bin/node]
 7: 0x105fdcd v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary>, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/bin/node]
 8: 0x10607fb v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::Add(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, int*) [/usr/bin/node]
 9: 0xec2cee  [/usr/bin/node]
10: 0x105a3d4 v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes) [/usr/bin/node]
11: 0x10738bb v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [/usr/bin/node]
12: 0x107aec0 v8::internal::JSObject::DefineOwnPropertyIgnoreAttributes(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::JSObject::AccessorInfoHandling) [/usr/bin/node]
13: 0x107e3f5 v8::internal::JSObject::CreateDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::ShouldThrow) [/usr/bin/node]
14: 0x108ff18 v8::internal::JSReceiver::CreateDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::ShouldThrow) [/usr/bin/node]
15: 0x11f6770 v8::internal::Runtime_CreateDataProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/bin/node]
16: 0x3ac05b24fc5d 
Aborted
```

I firstly thought that there is a code causing error, taking much heap space. However, it prints error when it doesn't even get to my very first code. It seems to break when it is receiving the post request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to send request data in chunks (smaller parts). A good example is [here](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/7511372). The example is for a file. However, if it is non-file data (e.g. text, JSON, XML), you can write it to a temp file, send that file  to your server in chunks and have the server read the file, to retrieve data you sent, once all chunks are received.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. For this case, it was caused by the error in md5 module.